# ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session. [0-0] Unable to connect to "http://localhost:4723/"

Tags: typescript, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android, wdio

ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
[0-0] Unable to connect to "http://localhost:4723/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.

```
jule@Ahmeds-MBP implement_typescript % npm run android.app

> automation@1.0.0 android.app
> wdio config/wdio.android.app.conf.ts


 Execution of 1 workers started at 2023-01-02T12:12:47.549Z

 2023-01-02T12:12:47.555Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
 2023-01-02T12:12:51.063Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
 2023-01-02T12:12:51.064Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: 
 config/wdio.android.app.conf.ts
 [0-0] 2023-01-02T12:12:51.409Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
 [0-0] RUNNING in Android - /test/specs/android/arive.e2e.ts
 [0-0] 2023-01-02T12:12:51.951Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the 
 WebDriver protocol
 [0-0] 2023-01-02T12:12:52.010Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session
 [0-0] 2023-01-02T12:12:52.010Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
 [0-0]   capabilities: {
 [0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
 [0-0]       platformName: 'Android',
 [0-0]       'appium:deviceName': 'emulator-5554',
 [0-0]       'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
 [0-0]       'appium:appPackage': 'com.getarive.app',
 [0-0]       'appium:appWaitActivity': 'com.getarive.app.MainActivity',
 [0-0]       'appium:app': '/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/app/android/arive-staging-v2.13.0-staging-release.apk',
 [0-0]       'appium:noReset': true
 [0-0]     },
 [0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
 [0-0]   },
 [0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
 [0-0]     platformName: 'Android',
 [0-0]     'appium:deviceName': 'emulator-5554',
 [0-0]     'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
 [0-0]     'appium:appPackage': 'com.getarive.app',
 [0-0]     'appium:appWaitActivity': 'com.getarive.app.MainActivity',
 [0-0]     'appium:app': '/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/app/android/arive-staging-v2.13.0-staging-release.apk',
 [0-0]     'appium:noReset': true
 [0-0]   }
 [0-0] }
 [0-0] 2023-01-02T12:12:52.044Z ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:4723
 [0-0]     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:970:111)
 [0-0]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
 [0-0]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
 [0-0]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
 [0-0]     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:43:20)
 [0-0]     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
 [0-0]     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
 [0-0]     at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
 [0-0]     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
 [0-0]     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
 [0-0]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
 [0-0] 2023-01-02T12:12:52.045Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
 [0-0] Unable to connect to "http://localhost:4723/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
 [0-0] If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
 [0-0]     at startWebDriverSession (/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:73:15)
 [0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
 [0-0]     at async Function.newSession (/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:46:45)
 [0-0]     at async remote (/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:78:22)
 [0-0]     at async Runner._startSession (/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:223:56)
 [0-0]     at async Runner._initSession (/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:176:25)
 [0-0]     at async Runner.run (/Users/jule/Desktop/arive/Arive-git-repo/implement_typescript/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:88:19)
 [0-0] FAILED in Android - /test/specs/android/arive.e2e.ts
 2023-01-02T12:12:52.171Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
 2023-01-02T12:12:52.172Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook
 Report successfully generated to allure-report
 Allure report successfully generated

 Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:06
```

Answer (score 1):

Found, Not supported with the node version - `v18.12.1`

Launching server now after - `nvm use 16`